# iOS Chrome search box changed to "new tab" button

Tags: ios, google-chrome

Google Chrome on my iPhone 8 Plus recently changed the search field at the bottom of the app interface to a "New Tab" button. (See screenshots below.) Does anyone know how to change it back? To be clear, I want the search field, not the plus-button.

I've tried deleting the app and then reinstalling it. Initially I got the search field at the bottom, but the plus-button reappears after a few uses.

If it helps, my iOS version is 13.3.1, and Google Chrome version is 80.0.3987.95.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this same issue and managed to figure out how to change it back.

Go to chrome://flags in a new tab, then search “new tab”. For the option “Enable new tab button in the bottom toolbar” select “Disable”.

Viola. [image]